# For loop always runs one less time then it should, due to two lines of code that appear unrelated to the for loop

Tags: java

Edit: For some reason my code works as intended in an online compiler. But in eclipse, the exact same code has the following problem.

I am working on a Kattis Problem called Electrical Outlets.
On the first line of input will be the number of test cases (n). On the next n lines, each line will start with an integer k, which is the number of power strips that will follow on the line. The rest of the line will contain how many outlets each of these power strips contain. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> outlets = new ArrayList<>();
        
        int testCases = scnr.nextInt();
        int stripCount;
        int appliances = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            stripCount = scnr.nextInt();
            for (int j = 0; j < stripCount; j++) {
                outlets.add(scnr.nextInt());
                appliances += outlets.get(j);
            }
            System.out.print("\nNumber of outlets: " + (appliances - (outlets.size() - 1)));
            System.out.print("\n" + i);
            outlets.clear();
            appliances = 0;
        }
    }
```

Now for some reason, the outer for loop always runs one less time then it should.
Here is a sample input

```
3
3 2 3 4
10 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 10 10 10 10
```

And expected output

```
Number of outlets: 7
Number of outlets: 31
Number of outlets: 37
```

However, my output is

```
Number of outlets: 7
Number of outlets: 31
```

Similarly, for input

```
5
5 4 3 2 5 6
4 3 2 2 3
7 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 4 3 3 4 4
8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

I expect an output of

```
Number of outlets: 16
Number of outlets: 7
Number of outlets: 22
Number of outlets: 14
Number of outlets: 65
```

But receive an output of

```
Number of outlets: 16
Number of outlets: 7
Number of outlets: 22
Number of outlets: 14
```

If I comment out the following two lines contained within for loop(int j)

```
            for (int j = 0; j < stripCount; j++) {
                //outlets.add(scnr.nextInt());
                //appliances += outlets.get(j);
            }
```

And add print(i), the for loop iterates as many times as it should.

Comment: Did you try to check, for example, what the value of `testCases` is after it's read? Whether the loop actually starts that many times? What the value of `stripCount` is each time through the loop? What values are put into `outlets`? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs.

Comment: Does your program *terminate* without printing the last line, or is it waiting for input?

Comment: Perhaps you don't have newline on the last line of your input, and aren't typing an end of file character?

Answer (score 0):

Kattis validates your code by inspecting your program's standard output. If even a single character is different than the judge expects, your submission will fail, and Kattis will only report "Wrong answer" without any reason, actual/expected diff or other diagnostics.

Therefore, it's critical to pay close attention to the expected output format in the problem description and sample test cases.

For the first sample input, we're given:

```
3
3 2 3 4
10 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 10 10 10 10
```

And the expected output is:

```
7
31
37
```

But your output is different:

```
Number of outlets: 7
0
Number of outlets: 31
1
Number of outlets: 37
2
```

This contains unnecessary `"Number of outlets: "` prefixes as well as an `i` for each test case. Sure, to a human, this is fine, but Kattis' runner program isn't smart enough to understand that you basically got it right.

Removing the `i` print and changing your result print to match what Kattis is asking for passes the submission tests:

```
System.out.println(appliances - (outlets.size() - 1));
```

As for the missing last line, you're probably not flushing that final buffer in the IDE. Either add a final newline or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> manually if you have interactive capabilities. This appears to be an environment misunderstanding, not a code problem.